# Magento Special price validation

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Sorry that I'm a total newbie in magento.

I have a multi-vendor magento site where vendors can create product. But when setting product price some users often do some mistakes. Some times special prices are higher than original price. I like to check this mistake. I want a validation script so that when vendors (who have limited admin access) create a new product then they should keep a minimum difference between special price and original price where special price is always lower than original price.

Can any body give some hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hope following code will help you

```
 <?php
 $product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(product_id);
 $price = $product->getPrice();
 $webprice = $product->getwebprice();
 $specialprice = $product->getFinalPrice();
 if($specialprice==$price)
 {?>
     <span>$<?php echo number_format($price,2);?></span>
     <?php } else if($specialprice<$price) { ?>
     <div>
        <span>Regular Price:</span>
        <span>$ <?php echo number_format($price,2); ?></span>
     </div>
     <div>
         <span>Web Special:</span>
         <span>$ <?php echo number_format($specialprice,2); ?> </span>
     </div>
  <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if the user set special prices more than original price,Magento takes cares of it by not displaying that special price .
However if you want to do some customization ,the path for price display is :**app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml**
It would be wise if you copy the structure, paste it on your custom theme and continue with your modification.
can add your javascript in **list.phtml (same product folder)**.
Hope it gives some hint.

Comment: Hi
Thanks for having time to answer my question. I was actually thinking of writing a validation script on admin panel so that when a product is being created I can check whether special price is higher than actual or not.